# How to redirect if from reddit with nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301

I post images on reddit by hotlinking images from my site. By allowing reddit to hotlink my images it will display the image on their site but I also want it to redirect if a user clicks on the image link from reddit. How can I do this while allowing hotlinking for reddit only?

Basically I'm trying to mimic the same way tumblr does with their images. Just try posting an image on reddit by hotlinking a tumblr image and it will display the image on their site and if you try to direct access the image it will redirect.

Example: https://www.reddit.com/user/HeavenlyTasty/comments/vqgn9r/demo_pic/

So far I thought of using nginx http referrer module but that doesn't achieve what I want it to do since it doesn't redirect if coming from reddit.

Anyone know another method to do this?

```
location ~* ^/(?<filenum>.*)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|webp)$ {
    proxy_pass http://195.xxx.xxx.xxx:7492;
    valid_referers none blocked server_names
               ~\.reddit\.;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    return 301 https://example.com/$filenum; 
}
```

Comment: _Just try posting an image on reddit by hotlinking a tumblr image_ - if you nave both tumblr and reddir accounts, post such an image and provide a link to this reddit post with your question.

Comment: @Ivan Shatsky posted the example link

Comment: I tried to reverse engineering tumblr behavior using the example link you provided. This was a really time-consuming, it would be nice to hear any (positive or negative) feedback.

Comment: If you checked the answer and found it workable, why didn't you award it with bounty?

Comment: @IvanShatsky but I already tick your answer with +50 bounty. Did you still not get it?

Comment: Yes, it is arrived, finally. When I wrote my previous comment, the grace period was over, so I thought the bounty was lost, since only the answers scored of two or more will be awarded automatically. Looks like some kind of internal delay is happened, everything is ok now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reverse engineered tumblr behavior. Decision to serve an image file or an HTML page is made according to the [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) HTTP request header. The trick is that this header value will vary depending on how is it requested - being entered at the browser address bar (or following the `<a>` tag hyperlink) or being referred via the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag. Here is a (somewhat inaccurate) [sample list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values) for various browsers from MDN and here are the actual `Accept` header values for several browsers (checked at the time of writing):

- Chrome 102

  `<a>` tag:

  ```
  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
  ```

  `<img>` tag:

  ```
  image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
  ```
- Firefox 102

  `<a>` tag:

  ```
  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
  ```

  `<img>` tag:

  ```
  image/avif,image/webp,*/*
  ```
- Safari 14.1 (MacOS Big Sur)

  `<a>` tag:

  ```
  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  ```

  `<img>` tag:

  ```
  image/webp,image/png,image/svg+xml,image/*;q=0.8,video/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
  ```
- Internet Explorer 11

  `<a>` tag:

  ```
  text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
  ```

  `<img>` tag:

  ```
  image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5
  ```

As you can see, a certain pattern can be observed for all browsers `Accept` header value. When an image is requested from the address bar (or via the `<a>` HTML tag), a `text/html` item is present in the accepted MIME types list; when an image is referred via `src` attibute of the `<img>` HTML tag, accepted MIME types list consists of `image/<MIME_subtype>` elements and the `*/*` element (except the Safari, where an aditional `video/*` item is present). If accepted MIME types list from the `Accept` header contains a `text/html` item, tumblr will serve such a request with an HTML page (except if the `User-Agent` header contains one of the well-known values for download managers, e.g. `curl`, `wget`, etc. - in this case, the server will still return the image). Note that tumblr won't give you a redirect to the HTML file. Instead it will serve the request with HTML file. The same request (with another `Accept` header) will be served later with the actual image file. Behaving like that, a properly configured server should warn the client browser (or intermediate proxy servers that may be present along the request/response route) that the content of the response may vary depending on certain request headers. The tumblr behaves exactly like that, adding the `Vary: Accept` header to the response. Here is an example requesting the same URL using two different `Accept` headers (`User-Agent` header removed from the request due to the aforementioned reasons):

```
> curl -I --http1.1 -H "Accept: */*" -H "User-Agent:" https://64.media.tumblr.com/f34905b055dc7fe1d7370bbea305662a/b3dcc022e27e2c22-f0/s1280x1920/84a7c043ea887caa2febb83ccd73c3c173a6beae.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2022 01:37:31 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 56077
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jul 2022 12:15:02 GMT
Etag: "9a02a2354a0fc8847dbddc91ff869735-1498089600-d32ddc9"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="tumblr_f34905b055dc7fe1d7370bbea305662a_84a7c043_1280.jpg"
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
...

> curl -I --http1.1 -H "Accept: text/html,*/*" -H "User-Agent:" https://64.media.tumblr.com/f34905b055dc7fe1d7370bbea305662a/b3dcc022e27e2c22-f0/s1280x1920/84a7c043ea887caa2febb83ccd73c3c173a6beae.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2022 01:37:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 17267
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept
ETag: W/"4373-SQYv0QHYV7hXuB2cQlEhOw0Czx4"
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
...
```

Issuing a 301 redirect with the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header can be an alternative; however, I'd rather use 302 temporary redirect instead:

```
map $invalid_referer $redirect {
    ''              $check_accept;
    default         1;
}
map $http_accept $check_accept {
    ~\btext/html\b  1;
}

server {
    ...
    location ~* ^/(?<filenum>.*)\.(jpe?g|png|webp)$ {
        proxy_pass http://195.xxx.xxx.xxx:7492;
        valid_referers none blocked server_names ~\.reddit\.;
        if ($redirect) {
            return 302 https://example.com/$filenum;
        }
    }
```

To completely mimic tumblr behavior you can try internal `rewrite ... last` instead of redirect (the `map` blocks will be the same as from the previous example):

```
server {
    ...
    location ~* ^/(?<filenum>.*)\.(jpe?g|png|webp)$ {
        proxy_pass http://195.xxx.xxx.xxx:7492;
        valid_referers none blocked server_names ~\.reddit\.;
        if ($redirect) {
            set $vary Accept;
            rewrite ^ /$filenum last;
        }
    }
    location ... {
        # location where rewritten request will be actually processed
        add_header Vary $vary;
        ...
```